# Why is my AngularJS model not defined?

Tags: angularjs

Here's my code:

```
<div ng-controller="EditModalCtrl">
        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Composer name" ng-model="media.composer" value="{{ media.composer }}" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Genre name" ng-model="media.genre" value="{{ media.genre }}" />
        </form>

        <button class="btn btn-branded" ng-click="updateSong(media);">Save</button>

</div>
```

When I hit the `Save` button, I get a Firebug console of `media is undefined`. Why would that be?

Comment: You shouldn't have to pass anything into that function, `$scope.media` should contain what you need back in the controller, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't need to send back anything in the `ng-click`. `media` (and all the attributes) will be accessible in the `$scope`. If that doesn't work, initialize `$scope.media = {}` in the controller.

Comment: Then how can I do my data updating via an API?

Comment: You use `$resource` and services for that. That's a separate issue. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its a typo, but it works perfectly with angular 1.0.8.

Checkout [this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/OjpyKVJ4HwLEP3FVvmOE?p=preview).
In console it will be logged.